# powershell ACLs Apply to this folder only

Tags: powershell, acl

When setting security descriptors, various resources provide the combination of PropagationFlags and InheritanceFlags to get the desired Apply to. Unfortunately documentation on these is sparse and clear explanation what these flags mean is even sparser. Yet, when I use the combination from those sources, I do not get the desired results. Specifically, to achieve Apply to = this folder only, both flags should be None, but when I do this, the result is Apply to this folder, subfolders and files. The combination that works though is PropagationFlags="InheritOnly" and InheritanceFlags="None". I am using powershell to set ACL.
Can someone comment on why is everybody claiming that they both should be none to get This folder while it apparently does not work?

Comment: not sure about the cause of your issue, but you might try manually setting the permissions as desired, then use powershell to get the acl for debugging

Answer (score 3):

The flags are documented on MSDN: [PropagationFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.propagationflags(v=vs.110).aspx), [InheritanceFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.inheritanceflags(v=vs.110).aspx) and the combination [ACL Propagation Rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229747(v=vs.110).aspx). When in doubt I usually create the access rule manually with GUI and see what it looks like using `(Get-ACL c:\path).Access`.

To create a "this folder only"-permission you need to set both inheritance and propagation to "None". Ex:

```
$acl = Get-Acl .\test
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule "BUILTIN\Users","ReadAndExecute", "None", "None","Allow"
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl -Path .\test -AclObject $acl
```

Be aware that `AddAccessRule` will ignore the change if there already is a less resitricted rule for the `BUILTIN\Users`. You would need to use something like `$acl.ModifyAccessRule("Set",$rule,[ref]$null)` to modify an exisiting one.

Comment: I am not sure that you read the post, I explicitly stated that if I set both to None, it does not work, the only combination that works is as is stated above.

Comment: I'm not sure you've tested my script. I executed it on a new folder 1 min ago and I got `This folder only`.

Comment: I am not saying, it does not work in you environment, but it does not in mine, there may be other problems as I never found a problem like this. If I use your code I get apply to this folder, subfolders and files as if the flags were ignored.

Comment: Which OS? If you create the rule using the GUI, what does it set the values to?

Comment: See "ACL Propagation Rules" link in updated answer. inheritance=None, Propagation=InheritOnly is an invalid (ignored) combination because nothing is inherited. None-None is `this folder only`. Test on a different computer with the same OS and one with a different version. There may be a bug on the specific computer, but that still doesn't make my answer wrong. Everyone is claiming it's supposed to be None-None becuase that is the correct combination